# Progress Bar depending on progressing in backend in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using django template and i have a button , when user click on this some actions performed in backend. For that time period i want to show a progress bar. here is my code for that button.

```
  $("#bulk_shortlist").click(function(){
        data=$('#limit option:selected').val()
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ settings.SITE_ADDR }}/hire/bulk_shortlisting/",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'limit': data,
                'id': {{ job_id }},
                'functional_area': options["functional_areas"],
                'min_exp':options["min_exp"],
                'max_exp':options["max_exp"],
                'min_sal':options["min_salary"],
                'max_sal':options["max_salary"],
                'age_cond':options["age_cond"],
                'gender':options["gender"],
                'industries':options["industries"],
                'languages':options["languages"],
                'adskills':options["adskills"],
                'location':options["location"],
                'education':options["education"]
            },
            success: function(response1) {
                alert(response1);
            },
            failure: function(response1) {
                alert('Got an error ..... Pleas try again later ');
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

I am very new in django , please help me out . Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to tag this with javascript or jquery?

Comment: i want to do this with jquery

Comment: Add the jquery tag to your tags and you might get more feedback.  You have tagged your question with django and django-templates so you have limited your audience to people who might not have jquery background